# I want property hive hook to get xml value and use it as status

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, plugins, hook

I want to get value of this <TRANS_TYPE_ID>  </TRANS_TYPE_ID> from property hive plugin , and use its value to give status rent or buy to admin panel status[image]

The problem is documentation I can not find it for this plugin, and also changing plugin code will not be a proper way to solve my task.

Answer (score 1):

Property Hive author here.

TRANS_TYPE_ID isn't a field in Property Hive. It looks like that comes from a BLM or 10ninety feed.

Also the 'Status' metabox shown in the screenshot isn't a Property Hive field. Is that maybe Houzez or similar? And if so, are you using one of the Property Hive data bridge add ons?

Comment: thanks, you are right I discovered this later. so basically I want to modify this status taxonomy to display buy or rent. it shows mostly available and I guess this comes from status_id. so I wrote this

Comment: `if($property->TRANS_TYPE_ID) {
        switch ($property->TRANS_TYPE_ID) {
            case '1':
                    wp_set_post_terms($post_id, 29, 'property_status', true);
                break;
            case '2':
                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, 28, 'property_status', true);
                break;
//            default:
//                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, 379 ,'property_status');
//                break;
        }`

Comment: but it added 28 and 29 as checkboxes inside the status. so my question is more about hook, is there anything to change the existing status to something new? wp_set_post_terms does not modify whats already is given to the property